# Need to store base64 data in local storage using vuex persist

Tags: vue.js, vuex

I have Vue.js webpage and its running in ios and android app.
I am trying to store 2 Base64 encoded image data in local Storage using vuex-persist.
But I repeatedly getting this error

> WKJavaScriptExceptionMessage = QuotaExceededError: The Quota has been exceeded.

It works well in Chrome browser, but getting error only while running in the app.

Comment: What sort of answer do you expect from this question?

Comment: How to solve this quotaExceederror?
I tried to save it has a object like
state.baseData.push(imageObject) But the Error keeps on displaying and nothing moved.

Comment: You are trying to store too much data. The answer is store less data

Comment: Yeah.. But I need to store 2 x Base64 image data in local storage. would you suggest any work around to solve this issue?